# Round unix time stamps in Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns, an id, and a unix timestamp (i.e. not Mysql style, but just a pure seconds from 1970 type.)

I want to know how many timestamps there are in each day.

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT unixtime, count(unixtime)
    AS count
    FROM core
    GROUP BY unixtime
```

What I need to do of course is to round the unixtime stamp up to the nearest day. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FROM_UNIXTIME` with `DATE` should get you the desired result:

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)), COUNT(unixtime) AS count
FROM core
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime))
```

Comment: This is kinda where I got to, but I really need the selected bit as a unix timestamp. I guess I'll just have to do that in PHP, rather than MYSQL.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your question. You can always convert back to a timestamp after.

Comment: I agree with njk, answer is exactly what you ask for, if you need unixtimestamp instead of date change on field select: "DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime))" by "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)))"

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer division to find the day (integer) since epoch.

```
# current day
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2014-04-16 14:52:06 |
+---------------------+

#number of days since epoch - there 86400
mysql> select unix_timestamp() div 86400 as days_since_epoch;
+------------------+
| days_since_epoch |
+------------------+
|            16176 |
+------------------+

#convert back to rounded off day
mysql> select from_unixtime((unix_timestamp() div 86400) * 86400) as today;
+---------------------+
| today               |
+---------------------+
| 2014-04-16 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unix_timestamp value (No. of seconds since 1/1/1970) and you want to remove the time portion from it you can use MySQL's MOD operator to find the remainder after dividing it by 86400 (The number of seconds in a day) and then subtracting that remainder from the original unix_timestamp value.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS date_time, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() MOD 86400) AS date_only;
```

Then you can group by this value.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34647788)